# Redux counter basic example does not increment count

Tags: redux

I am creating the most basic example of applying Redux with React to practice what I have been learning last two days, simple application to get counter state from store and increment it, that is it.

The code does everything right, and it does dispatch an action (it does console log the action type and value also inside reducer also), but It doesn't increment counter.

If you are experienced with Redux you can check the reducer directly, I think the problem is there.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

import {createStore} from "redux";

var initialState = {
  count: 5
};

function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  console.log(action)
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD":
      return {
        count: state.count + action.value
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

var store = createStore(reducer, initialState);

class App extends React.Component {
  increment = () => {
    store.dispatch({type: "ADD", value: 1});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello Counter Redux app</h1>
        <button onClick={this.increment}> click to increment number</button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <b> {store.getState().count} </b>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: The counter is not incremented in your App component ( in redux store it does increments) because App component is not connected with redux store which basically means it is not subscribed to store updates. You need to use connect function from `react-redux` package and wrap your App component inside `Provider` component from the same package

Comment: Your store actually updates but your component dosen't because it is not [connected](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) to the store, check this sandbox console to see the store each time you dispatch an action I've added the code in line 25-27 to `console.log` the store after each update [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vv0llm2z37)

Comment: I added provider and store.subscribe(), in this codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/xj8p9o9x94 it shows in console log the correct count but it doesn't update inside app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a few revisions to your code - first, consider making use of `react-redux` to bind your store to your `<App/>` component.

Taking the `react-redux` based approach, you'll want to use the `connect()` method that this package provides, to connect your `<App/>` component to your actions and store:

```
const ConnectedApp = connect(
  state => {
    return {
      count: state.count
    };
  },
  dispatch => {
    return {
      increment: () => dispatch({ type: "ADD", value: 1 })
    };
  }
)(App);
```

Doing this exposes two additional props to your `<App/>` component: the `count` value (taken directly from store state) and the `increment()` function (which dispatches the action to your reducer). Notice that the `connect()` method returns a new version of your component `<ConnectedAdd />` (which is used in the next step).

Next, you'll want to use the `<Provider />` to mount your store to your app in the following way:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

Finally, a bit of refactoring to your `<App/>` component's `render()` method completes this process:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello Counter Redux app</h1>
        <button onClick={this.props.increment}>
          {" "}
          click to increment number
        </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <b> {this.props.count} </b>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The react redux "stuff" can be a bit to get your head around at first but once you've worked with it a bit, it starts to make more sense - stick at it :-)

For a [full working example please see this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4r370j5jnw)